# run a number of functions over data in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I wanted to write a code which gets several .txt and .ASC data. All of those have to be run through some functions. So I thought it would be great to have a script which is doing it automatically.

The .txt contains more data (product, number, color, size) than the .ASC (product, number, size). So I have to adjust the head of each.

So, this is the first part of what I thought my script could look like.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import new_methods as nem
import sys
sys.path.append("../../src/")

path_data ="C:///Users///"

fids = [file for file in os.listdir(path_data)]

d = dict()
for i in fids:
    if i[-1]== 't':
        d.update({i : nem.df(path_data+i, header_lines=1)})
    elif i[-1] == 'C':
        d.update({i : nem.df(path_data+i, header_lines=0)})

for val in d.values():
    txt_fid=d[val]
    dh_txt=nem.sort(txt_fid)
```

But it gives a Typeerror

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

It does work if I change the last part to

```
txt_fid=d['specific.txt']
dh_txt=nem.sort(txt_fid)
```

But like this I have to change manually for every txt sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says you cannot have a key in a dictionary that is mutable (such as a DataFrame), which you are doing when you do `d[val]` because `val` is a DataFrame.

Did you mean to use the value of the dictionary or did you want the keys? Or some element of the DataFrame perhaps?

If you want the keys and not the values, you can simply do `for val in d:` instead.